# $\Vert x \Vert \leq 1 \implies \Vert x^{1/2} \Vert \leq 1$ in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $x \in A$ a positive element with $\Vert x \Vert \leq 1$. Is it true that $\Vert x^{1/2}\Vert \leq 1?$

**Attempt**: Note that $C^*(x)$ is an abelian $C^*$-algebra, so we can consider the Gelfand representation
$$\phi: C^*(x) \to C_0(\Omega)$$
where $\Omega$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Note that $\phi$ preserves (positive) square roots of positive elements because these are unique. Put $f:= \phi(x)$. Then $\Vert f^{1/2}\Vert_\infty \leq 1$ holds trivially so also $\Vert x^{1/2}\Vert \leq 1$. Hence, we are done.

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^{1/2}$ is also positive and in particular self-adjoint so by $C^*$-property we have
$$\left\|x^{1/2}\right\|^2 = \left\|\left(x^{1/2}\right)^*x^{1/2}\right\| = \|x\| \le 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is correct. Perhaps you need also to explain that every element $x^{1/2}$ (there may be several a-priory) belongs to
$C^*(x)$.

**Edit.** Sorry I forgot that the positive square root of a positive element in a  $C^*$-algebra is unique and belongs to $C^*(x)$. But it would be better if you refer to that result. It is not completely obvious.

Comment: It is not true that every square root of $x$ belongs to $C^*(x)$ (the $C^*$-algebra generated by $x$).  For example, in the $2 \times 2$ matrices, take $x = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ has infinitely many square roots, of which only $x$ and $-x$ are in $C^*(x)$.  But the positive square root is unique and does belong to $C^*(x)$.

Comment: The OP says that $x$ is positive and he is considering a positive root. But the OP should have mentioned that theorem. That is what my edit is about.